# Помощь в верстке!

Tags: css3, html5

Ребят, как мне из этого [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделать вот это [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На кружки не обращайте внимания

HTML

```
<div class="reviews">
       <div class="main_thagolovokr">
         Reviews
       </div>
       <div class="stolbikir">
         <div class="stolbikr1">
           <div class="review1">
              Porro officia cumque sint deleniti nemo facere rem vitae odit inventore<br>
               cum odio, iste quia doloribus autem aperiam nulla ea neque reprehen-<br>
              derit. Libero doloribus, possimus officiis sapiente necessitatibus<br>
               commodi consectetur?
           </div>
           <div class="review2">
             Porro officia cumque sint deleniti nemo facere rem vitae odit inventore<br>
              cum odio, iste quia doloribus autem aperiam nulla ea neque reprehen-<br>
             derit. Libero doloribus, possimus officiis sapiente necessitatibus<br>
              commodi consectetur?
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="stolbikr2">
           <div class="review3">
             Porro officia cumque sint deleniti nemo facere rem vitae odit inventore<br>
              cum odio, iste quia doloribus autem aperiam nulla ea neque reprehen-<br>
             derit. Libero doloribus, possimus officiis sapiente necessitatibus<br>
              commodi consectetur?
           </div>
           <div class="review4">
             Porro officia cumque sint deleniti nemo facere rem vitae odit inventore<br>
              cum odio, iste quia doloribus autem aperiam nulla ea neque reprehen-<br>
             derit. Libero doloribus, possimus officiis sapiente necessitatibus<br>
              commodi consectetur?
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
.stolbikir {
  display: flex;
}
.stolbikr1,
.stolbikr2 {
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.review1 {
  padding-top: 26px;
  margin-left: 153px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #445162;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}
.review2 {
  padding-top: 26px;
  margin-left: 153px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #445162;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}
.review3 {
  padding-top: 26px;
  margin-left: 134px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #445162;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}
.review4 {
  padding-top: 26px;
  margin-left: 134px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #445162;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}
```

Comment: Вам нужны только стрелки(треугольники) http://prntscr.com/n3lmkb ?

Comment: Да вообще всё нужно помочь сделать так же

Comment: вообще все - это на фриланс)

Comment: Не то, что бы вообще за меня, а именно помочь, подсказать и так далее. Для этого этот сайт и был создан)

Comment: для того, чтобы помочь нужна конкретная проблема, т.е., например, "не получается сделать стрелки", а не "всё нужно помочь сделать так же". Отступы и курсив Вы и сами можете сделать. Если нет, то http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.stolbikir {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.review1,
.review2,
.review3,
.review4 {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-left: 153px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #445162;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}

.review1::after,
.review2::after,
.review3::after,
.review4::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid #ebebeb;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="reviews">
  <div class="main_thagolovokr">
    Reviews
  </div>
  <div class="stolbikir">
    <div class="stolbikr1">
      <div class="review1">
        Porro officia cumque sint deleniti nemo facere rem vitae odit inventore<br> cum odio, iste quia doloribus autem aperiam nulla ea neque reprehen-<br> derit. Libero doloribus, possimus officiis sapiente necessitatibus<br> commodi consectetur?
      </div>
      <div class="review2">
        Porro officia cumque sint deleniti nemo facere rem vitae odit inventore<br> cum odio, iste quia doloribus autem aperiam nulla ea neque reprehen-<br> derit. Libero doloribus, possimus officiis sapiente necessitatibus<br> commodi consectetur?
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="stolbikr2">
      <div class="review3">
        Porro officia cumque sint deleniti nemo facere rem vitae odit inventore<br> cum odio, iste quia doloribus autem aperiam nulla ea neque reprehen-<br> derit. Libero doloribus, possimus officiis sapiente necessitatibus<br> commodi consectetur?
      </div>
      <div class="review4">
        Porro officia cumque sint deleniti nemo facere rem vitae odit inventore<br> cum odio, iste quia doloribus autem aperiam nulla ea neque reprehen-<br> derit. Libero doloribus, possimus officiis sapiente necessitatibus<br> commodi consectetur?
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```